# Recommendations for a good vi reference?

Tags: reference, vi

As I don't use vi all that much and certainly not for my primary editor, I can't remember any of the vi commands.  Does anyone have a recommendation for a quick start guide or command summary?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is the best to keep in your desk, full of coffee works great :-)

[image: Vi Mug]
<sub>(source: [thinkgeek.com](https://www.thinkgeek.com/images/products/front/vi_mug.jpg))</sub>

[The Mug of Vi References](https://web.archive.org/web/20150602103646/http://www.thinkgeek.com/interests/exclusives/7bbe/)

I also like the [VI Editor Pocket Reference](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1565924975) book.

Answer (score 7):

[Learning the vi editor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1565924266) by Arnold Robbins and Linda Lamb

[image]

A [little companion](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1565924975) for quick reference (by A. Robbins) is also available.

Comment: Ah yes, the ... what the hell is that thing?... book.

Comment: LOL, they must have got out of known animals some years ago, so probably they resorted to a zoology text :D

Comment: Not to mention sed & awk: http://www.amazon.com/sed-awk-2nd-Dale-Dougherty/dp/1565922255 Are those some kind of monkeys?

Comment: I like very much the 7th Edition, has great chapters about Vim... http://tinyurl.com/5fjajp

Comment: @Frederico:  WTH??  Those things are scary looking.  Like wingless bats or something.  :)

Comment: The animal on the cover is a Tarsier, a nocturnal mammal related to the lemur...

Answer (score 5):

A good cheat sheet you can print out is here: http://www.viemu.com/a_vi_vim_graphical_cheat_sheet_tutorial.html

Answer (score 3):

type `vim-tutor`

Comment: Vim is unfortunately not the only vi clone in use.

Comment: Vim's documentation is extremely well-written and points out every time something works different to vi (or "compatibility mode").

Answer (score 2):

http://www.vim.org/htmldoc/

It is a html version of the help also available from vim itself with the :help command.

Answer (score 1):

I started to use vi recently. One way to get references is to bookmark some commonly used commands:

- [VIM Introduction and Turoial](https://stackoverflow.com/users/30907/davidchuca). I
  referred to this many times at the
  beginning. Now I use it less often
- [VIM Quick References Card](http://tnerual.eriogerg.free.fr/vimqrc.html).
  Quick reference by groups.

I added some links like those to my [foxmarks](http://www.foxmarks.com/) so that I can sync these links at home and work.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent book, and links in other answers. If you are in Vim, don't forget the old faithful:

```
<ESC>:he<Return>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this vi reference: http://www.digitahsystems.com/vi_ref.html